# Eclipse IDE Debugger does not find sources

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-juno

There is some strange behaviour in  Eclipse IDE:

- I added some sources to a jar, and now I can inspect the classes.
- Unfortunately, the debugger does not find the sources, so i am seeing the "Edit Source Lookup Button". using the button to point to the sources again - doesnt work.

What i did:
- I explicitely added the sources to the Run Configuration. They atre not found by debugger either.

What is going wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots it seems like the missing sources are those for the ClassNotFoundException class (part of JDK/JRE), while you're only showing there are sources attached to some project-specific jars.

If this is the case, the sources of the JDK are to be attached separately (on windows systems, if you have a JDK rather that a JRE, they should attach themselves automatically when you register it in eclipse)